# How do I enable experimental printf functions in MinGW w64?

Tags: c, mingw-w64

MinGW-w64 mentioned this in the v4 changelog:

> "Experimental printf changes - Ability to print 128bit integers (%I128*) and Decimal Floats (%H, %D), disabled by default. Build the CRT with --enable-experimental to use."

How do I enable this? What is the "CRT"?

I haven't figured anything out yet. I'm using the WinLibs version of MinGW w64.

Comment: The "CRT" is the Windows MSVC run-time library which is used by MinGW and GCC. The option `--enable-experimental` is an option used when building GCC from sources. It's not something which can be added or toggled later.

Comment: And considering that these features are experimental and non-standard and therefore non-portable, what is the underlying problem that you believe having them would solve?

Comment: Thanks you for your help. As for the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm just trying to print decimals (Decimal32, Decimal64, Decimal128).